# Migrate taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I am looking for a way to import Nodes to D8 from a source using Json Api
The node is having terms referenced but i cant find a way neither a tutorial to import and then reference thoses terms to the node

Any solution please Or example ?

Here how the object looks like

```
"field_terms": {
      "data": {
        "type": "taxonomy_term--terms",
        "id": "e6009802-3eef-4ffb-ac70-dab49bbd9b27"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https:\/\/website.com\/jsonapi\/node\/events\/34b9123c-d3cf-49e6-827b-946b59d46542\/relationships\/field_terms?resourceVersion=id%3A379"
        },
        "related": {
          "href": "https:\/\/website.com\/jsonapi\/node\/events\/34b9123c-d3cf-49e6-827b-946b59d46542\/field_terms?resourceVersion=id%3A379"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Did you look at Migrate Plus? You can create migrations from JSON sources.

Comment: Yes of course but the Json source are really differents than the object rendered by Json APi

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have written migrations that import both custom JSON objects and those that conform to JSON API spec.

Comment: Then can you share how you process terms & nodes exported with Json API Custom json have keu values . that is easy to parse ex :  ` "status": true,  ` actually in in the exemple the relationship object contains key and values that cannot be directy imported .. i have no term name no tid no parent . as you can see in the code i posted